# Figure out where my program hangs up using GDB?

Tags: c, gdb

**How would I get all stack traces for all threads in GDB?**

I need to figure out where my program hangs up and whether an external framework is causing it. I need something like the `backtrace` command but one that gets all traces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`thread apply all <command>` runs `<command>` for all threads, for example:

```
(gdb) thread apply all backtrace
```

Additionally, you might find the following useful: [`gdb` manual - Debugging Programs with Multiple Threads](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html#Threads).